# Resize ToolStrip Button Image programatically at startup via toolstrip.ImageScalingSize

Tags: vb.net, image, resize, toolstrip

So I've read around this and will provide relevant properties at the end.

I'm looking to store a custom ToolStrip button image size in my.settings and load them at startup, changing them to a user set size.. The code I run at startup is:

```
    Dim tss As New List(Of ToolStrip)
    tss = GetAllControls(Me).OfType(Of ToolStrip)().ToList

    For Each ts In tss
        ts.BackColor = My.Settings.ToolStripBGColor
        ts.ImageScalingSize = New Size(My.Settings.ToolStripImgScalingSize, My.Settings.ToolStripImgScalingSize)
        ts.ResumeLayout()
        ts.Invalidate()
        ts.Refresh()
    Next

    ToolStripContainer.Invalidate()
    ToolStripContainer.Refresh()
```

This does change the properties of all of the ToolStips. However, the images initially display at the default 16x16 UNTIL I drag them into another area of the ToolStripContainer. It then resizes correctly. This tends to imply to me that it's something to so with the draw of these containers/controls (hence the blanket bombing of .invalidate, .resumelayout and .refresh!)

Regarding proprieties, the relevant ones within designer view:

**ToolStripButton**

.autosize = true

.imagescaling = SizeToFit

**ToolStrip**

.autosize = true

.imagesclaing = 16,16 (later modified by code)

**ToolStripContainer**

- couldn't see any that would effect this!??

This is one of those where you go round in circles for half a day over what essentially could be due to a janky aspect of .net! Could be me though...

Answer (score 2):

Getting this to work with `AutoSize=True` is always a bit confusing. I've found that if you set it to `False` with layout suspended and then set it to `True` with layout enabled, that you can get the desired effect.

That description is probably clear as mud, so here is the code pattern.

```
    With ToolStrip1
        .SuspendLayout()
        .AutoSize = False
        .ImageScalingSize = New Size(40, 40)
        .ResumeLayout()
        .AutoSize = True
    End With
```

Answer (score 0):

Imports System.Drawing : Imports Microsoft.VisualBasic

Imports Microsoft.Win32 : Imports System

Imports System.IO : Imports System.Windows.Forms

```
Public Class Form1

    Inherits Form
```

Private toolStripItem1 As ToolStripButton

Private toolStrip1 As ToolStrip

Public Sub New()

```
toolStrip1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip()

toolStrip1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(580,40)

toolStrip1.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.MistyRose

toolStrip1.AutoSize = True

toolStripItem1 = New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton()    
    
toolStrip1.SuspendLayout()

Me.SuspendLayout()

toolStrip1.Items.AddRange(New System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripButton() _

{toolStripItem1})

toolStrip1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(0, 0)

toolStrip1.Name = "toolStrip1"

toolStripItem1.AutoSize = False

toolStripItem1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(110,95)

toolStripItem1.BackgroundImage = Image.FromFile("D:\Book4\Resources\icos\CUT.png")

toolStripItem1.Name = "toolStripItem1"

toolStripItem1.Text = "Cut"

toolStripItem1.Font = New System.Drawing.Font("Segoe UI", 16.0!, _

System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, _

                             CType(0, Byte))

toolStripItem1.TextAlign = System.Drawing.ContentAlignment.TopCenter

AddHandler Me.toolStripItem1.Click, New System.EventHandler _

                                 (AddressOf Me.toolStripItem1_Click)

Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F)

Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font

Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(1500,900)

Me.BackColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#808080")

Me.Controls.Add(Me.toolStrip1)

Me.Name = "Form1"

toolStrip1.ResumeLayout(False)

Me.ResumeLayout(False)

Me.PerformLayout()
```

End Sub

Public Sub Form1_Loaded(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _

```
                       Handles MyBase.Load
```

Try

```
  Dim ico As New System.Drawing.Icon("D:\Resources\icos\kvr.ico")

  Me.Icon = ico
```

Catch ex As Exception

End Try

End Sub

Public Shared Sub Main()

```
Dim form1 As Form1 = New Form1()

form1.ShowDialog()
```

End Sub

Private Sub toolStripItem1_Click(ByVal sender As Object,ByVal e As EventArgs)

```
System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Successfully enlarged ToolStripButtonImage size")
```

End Sub

End Class

Comment: Compile this Form you get a 110,95 size ToolStripButton Image.Paths syntax must be corrected to your use.Download scissors image resize it to 52x52 size.Use the path of the image.